# Bootstrap 3: Horizontal form group inside dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The requirement is a horizontal form group inside of a dropdown. When the user clicks the dropdown, they are able to enter text into the appearing text fields.

I am losing control over the width and margin of the form group when inside of the dropdown. For example, the following form group renders fine:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="strike-from" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strike-from" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="strike-to" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strike-to" value=""">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

However when embedding this same HTML inside of a dropdown wrapper, the text fields extend past the container and the margin is compressed.

[image: Bad]

```
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="strikes-range" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
            Strikes
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="strikes">
            <li>
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="strike-from" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strike-from" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="strike-to" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strike-to" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there an out of the box implementation of this? Otherwise do I just need to add custom styles for width of text boxes and margin?

Or am I just implementing something incorrectly?

Comment: could you please tell what `form-line` class do ? 
Are you referring this ? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

This is `form-inline` class not `form-line`

If this is your own class. Please post the Css for `form-line` also

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I was rushing. This is `form-inline`, bootstrap's tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited some `column widths` and removed an extra `"` and added a class `donotchange` for removing the alignment error.

Here is my code

> **HTML**

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="strikes-range" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"> Strikes <span class="caret"></span> </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="strikes">
        <li style="width: 280px;">
          <form class="form-horizontal" style="display:block;">
            <div class="form-group donotchange">
              <label for="strike-from" class="col-sm-2 control-label">From</label>
              <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strike-from" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group donotchange">
              <label for="strike-to" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
              <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strike-to" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group donotchange">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- No need. For checking Only-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="strikes-range" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"> Sample Button </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="strike-to" value="">
  </div>
<!-- No need. For checking Only-->

</div>
```

> **CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
.form-inline .donotchange {
     display: block; 
     margin-bottom: 10px; 
     vertical-align: middle; 
}
.form-horizontal .donotchange {
     margin-right: 0px; 
     margin-left: 0px; 
}}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.form-inline .donotchange {
    display: block; 
     margin-bottom: 10px; 
     vertical-align: middle; 
}}
```

Check my working code here http://www.bootply.com/N0lccYSCsg

Check whether it works as per your requirements.
Good day!

Comment: This works but forgot to mention the whole thing is wrapped in a `<div class="form-line">` tag which breaks it again. OP updated.

Comment: Please post the full code for the menu so that i can replicate yout problem in my system

Comment: This is the code. If you paste what I have posted into Bootply, the problem is replicated.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102549/discussion-between-dino-and-strimp099).